# (XCODE)Text view: shows bottom of text as first

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scroll, textview

I saw a lot of similar questions but no answer didn't help me.
I have table view with static cells. Every cell is connected with View Controller with text view. Every text view has long text, which has to be scrolled. Unfortunately after moving to this view with text, I see bottom of text instead of top of it.

This is how this part with view controllers in storyboard looks like http://imgur.com/cndYyYV

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this while updating text in textView?

```
[textView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```